# What is the correct way to refine a feature request?

Tags: discussion, edits, feature-request-process

Suppose I post a feature request, and someone points out a problem with the way it would work in a certain scenario. Further, suppose I agree that this is a real problem, but there's also a way to modify it to not have this problem.

Should I submit a new, separate, feature request or should I edit the existing feature request?

Comment: Just edit it; no point in cluttering the site with iterations of a proposal.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Edit your suggestion.

Unless your suggestion is changing *completely* and *fundamentally*, you're just improving it. You might as well just edit it rather than clutter the site with 3 very slightly different versions of the same thing.